# How to use a mask to limit broadcasted operations between two numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

I have an array like so:

```
data = np.array([
    [[10, 10, 10],
     [10, 10, 10],
     [10, 10, 10]],

    [[20, 20, 20],
     [20, 20, 20],
     [20, 20, 20]],

    [[30, 30, 30],
     [30, 30, 30],
     [30, 30, 30]],
], dtype=np.float64)
```

and one to divide values by, like so:

```
divide_by = np.array([
    [[10, 10, 1]],
    [[1, 10, 10]],
    [[1, 1, 1]],
], dtype=np.float64)
```

I would like to divide each row (axis 0) of the `data` array by values in the `divide_by` array (sort of like a stamp), but only in positions where a given mask (which as the shape of `data`) has been set to `True`.

So the first part I can achieve by:

```
divide_by = divide_by.reshape(divide_by.shape[0], divide_by.shape[2])

data /= divide_by

print(data)
```

Which yields:

```
[[[ 1.  1. 10.]
  [10.  1.  1.]
  [10. 10. 10.]]

 [[ 2.  2. 20.]
  [20.  2.  2.]
  [20. 20. 20.]]

 [[ 3.  3. 30.]
  [30.  3.  3.]
  [30. 30. 30.]]]
```

Note that each row of the `data` array has been divided by what's in `divide_by` as if that had been applied like a stamp on top of it. Great.

I would like to do the same now, but only apply the division in places where this mask is set to true:

```
mask = np.array([
    [[False, True, False],
     [False, False, False],
     [True, False, False]],

    [[True, True, True],
     [False, False, True],
     [False, False, False]],

    [[True, False, False],
     [False, False, False],
     [False, False, False]],
])
```

So that the expected output is:

```
[[[10.  1. 10.]
  [10. 10.  1.]
  [10. 10. 10.]]

 [[ 2.  2. 20.]
  [20. 20.  2.]
  [20. 20. 20.]]

 [[ 3. 30. 30.]
  [30. 30. 30.]
  [30. 30. 30.]]]
```

The mask is defining a subset of places to divide by,

But if I do:

```
data[mask] /= divide_by
```

instead of

```
data /= divide_by
```

I get:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (3,3) (7,)
```

How can I use this mask in this particular case?

Comment: Since `mask` has 7 True values, `data[mask]` is a flat array of 7 elements.  You have to somehow apply `mask` (or something else) to `divide_by` to produce a like size 7 element array.

Comment: `np.divide`, like other `ufunc` takes a `where` (and `out`) parameter that lets you apply the division to a subset of the elements.  But given your mix of shapes it would take a bit of interactive testing to get the mix right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where(mask, data / divide_by[None, :, 0], data)`.

Comment: Thank you, I will study this solution now, it works great!